# What is a need of defining indegree vector in private for finding All Topological Sorts of DAG?

Tags: oop, c++11, graph

What is the importance of defining `indegree` vector in the private of a class? It could have been defined in alltopologicalSort() function.

```
class Graph 
{ 
int V;    // No. of vertices 

// Pointer to an array containing adjacency list 
list<int> *adj; 

// Vector to store indegree of vertices 
vector<int> indegree; 

// A function used by alltopologicalSort 
void alltopologicalSortUtil(vector<int>& res, 
                            bool visited[]); 

public: 
Graph(int V);   // Constructor 

// function to add an edge to graph 
void addEdge(int v, int w); 

// Prints all Topological Sorts 
void alltopologicalSort(); 
};
```

And how it is functioning in below addedge function

```
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) 
{ 
adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v's list. 

// increasing inner degree of w by 1 
indegree[w]++; 
}
```

Use of indegree, please explain here the role of addEdge function in decrementing indegree

```
void Graph::alltopologicalSortUtil(vector<int>& res, 
                               bool visited[]) 
{ 
// To indicate whether all topological are found 
// or not 
bool flag = false;  

for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
{ 
    //  If indegree is 0 and not yet visited then 
    //  only choose that vertex 
    if (indegree[i] == 0 && !visited[i]) 
    { 
        //  reducing indegree of adjacent vertices 
        list<int>:: iterator j; 
        for (j = adj[i].begin(); j != adj[i].end(); j++) 
            indegree[*j]--; 

        //  including in result 
        res.push_back(i); 
        visited[i] = true; 
        alltopologicalSortUtil(res, visited); 

        // resetting visited, res and indegree for 
        // backtracking 
        visited[i] = false; 
        res.erase(res.end() - 1); 
        for (j = adj[i].begin(); j != adj[i].end(); j++) 
            indegree[*j]++; 

        flag = true; 
      } 
     }
 }
```

This is the link to complete code of finding All Topological Sorts of Directed Acyclic Graph
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-topological-sorts-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph/

Comment: I think the answer to this is probably "you don't *need* to, but the author of the code *chose* to".

Comment: @kaya3 It could NOT have been defined in alltopologicalSort() function, because it is used in other methods like `addEdge()` method.

Comment: @Gupta Obviously, if it were not defined in the class then the class's `addEdge` method would not maintain its state, and the other method would have to do that. That is a trivial refactoring, not an insurmountable barrier.

Comment: @kaya3 So, the answer of the Q is not "you don't need to, but the author of the code chose to". The answer is "You should define indegree at class level because it is shared by other methods."

Comment: @Gupta There are two different ways it could have been designed. The question asks why one instead of the other. If you want to assume the question is simply caused by the OP making a trivial mistake, go ahead, but I see no reason to assume that. Either way, *"It could NOT have been defined in alltopologicalSort()"* is wrong; it could have been, if it were designed the other way.

Comment: I think @Gupta is right. It could have been defined in some function and then passed to alltopologicalSort() function as a reference. But then defining it in class makes it easier to deal with.

Comment: Could I define indegree in the public part of the class?

Comment: @KRN Yes, you can do it, but NEVER do it. Data members of a class are always kept private because of encapsulation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer from above discussion with Gupta and kaya3

Indegree could have been defined in some function and then passed to alltopologicalSort() function as a reference. But then defining it in class makes it easier to deal with.

And Data members of a class are always kept private because of encapsulation rules